# Android CircularReveal library View visibility bug

Tags: android, animation, view, invisible, circularreveal

I use [this](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal) libary to create CircularReveal animation on pre-Lollipop devices. The problem is in hiding `View` with animation. Animation is performed as well, but after animation end, `View` become visible for a second and then disappears. How can I prevent blinking of `View`?

Here is my method for hiding `View` with CircularReveal animation:

```
public static void revealCloseTopRight(final View view) {
            int cx = view.getRight();
            int cy = view.getTop();

            // get the final radius for the clipping circle
            int dx = Math.max(cx, view.getWidth() - cx);
            int dy = Math.max(cy, view.getHeight() - cy);
            float finalRadius = (float) Math.hypot(dx, dy);

            SupportAnimator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
            animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            animator.setDuration(animDuration);
            animator = animator.reverse();

            try {
                animator.start();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }, animDuration);
        }
```

**UPDATE**

I also tried to add `SupportAnimator.AnimatorListener()` like this:

```
animator.addListener(new SupportAnimator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart() {
                    Log.d(AnimationSupport.TAG, TAG + " -> 1onAnimationStart()");

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd() {
                    Log.d(AnimationSupport.TAG, TAG + " -> 1onAnimationEnd()");
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel() {
                    Log.d(AnimationSupport.TAG, TAG + " -> 1onAnimationCancel()");

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat() {
                    Log.d(AnimationSupport.TAG, TAG + " -> 1onAnimationRepeat()");

                }
            });
```

And `Animator.AnimatorListener()` like this:

```
animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    Log.d(AnimationSupport.TAG, TAG + " -> onAnimationStart()");

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    Log.d(AnimationSupport.TAG, TAG + " -> onAnimationEnd()");
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    Log.d(AnimationSupport.TAG, TAG + " -> onAnimationCancel()");

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                    Log.d(AnimationSupport.TAG, TAG + " -> onAnimationRepeat()");

                }
            });
```

In both cases none on this callbacks are never called. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in your layout where you're trying to animate the view, there is no

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

property in the root viewGroup.

Removing that will help you to overcome blinking view after animation end and setting visibility to GONE (or INVISIBLE).

Answer (score 0):

The view is being visible because there is a very small delay between the animation completing and your handler's execution.

You can solve this problem by adding an animation listener to your circular reveal animation and setting the view to invisible in the `onAnimationEnd()` callback.

Comment: I tried to do like this. The problem is that `onAnimationEnd()` is never called and I have no idea why. So, I decided to use `postDelayed()` and now I have blinking `View`